# Is this possible to change subset of string to numeric value?

Tags: r, string

Let's take for example text following :

```
x<-'RMSE_coef= -0.6 MAE_coef=-0.4'
```

what I want to do is to create to extract those values -0.6 and -0.4 from x and change them to numeric values.

It would be very easy after extracting those numbers from x (we just can use function `as.numeric()`) and the problem is over. The question is - how to get those values ?

*EDIT*

Is there any possibility of one code which can do it for generic case ? I mean for :

```
x<-'RMSE_coef= -0.6 MAE_coef=-0.4'
x<-'RMSE_coef= 0.6 MAE_coef=0.4'
x<-'RMSE_coef= 0.6 MAE_coef=-0.4'
x<-'RMSE_coef= -0.6 MAE_coef=0.4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A alternative solution with the rebus packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rebus)
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

pattern <- optional("-") %R% one_or_more(DGT) %R% DOT %R% one_or_more(DGT)


x <-'RMSE_coef= -0.6 MAE_coef=-0.4'

stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(x, pattern) %>% 
  purrr::map(as.numeric)

[[1]]
[1] -0.6 -0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit((gsub('.*(\\d\\.\\d).*(\\d\\.\\d)','\\1 \\2',x)),' ')))
[1] 0.6 0.4
```

Including minus sign:

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit((gsub('.*(-\\d\\.\\d).*(-\\d\\.\\d)','\\1 \\2',x)),' ')))
[1] -0.6 -0.4
```

Using stringr :

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all('RMSE_coef= -0.6 MAE_coef=-0.4', '-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+')))
[1] -0.6 -0.4
as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all('RMSE_coef= 0.6 MAE_coef=0.4',   '-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+')))
[1] 0.6 0.4
as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all('RMSE_coef= 0.6 MAE_coef=-0.4',  '-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+')))
[1]  0.6 -0.4
as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all('RMSE_coef= -0.6 MAE_coef=0.4',  '-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+')))
[1] -0.6  0.4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there any possibility how can I extract minuses too ? ;))

Comment: @John, have updated my answer. Please check if that works for you.

Comment: Hmm okay I see! Thank you very much! Maybe one last question. Do you think if there is a solution which can do it for any real numbers (with no diversity- with minus or without). Just one code which works for all cases ;))

Comment: I will edit my answer to give you better look on what I'm searching